# Backward Euler method approximation of discretization problem exact solution

Tags: numerical-methods, control-theory

In Wikipedia, there's an exact solution of [Discretization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization#Derivation)
, which says the state-space model

$$
\dot{x} = Ax(t) + Bu(t)
$$

can be discretized to

$$
x[k+1] = e^{AT}x[k] + A^{-1} (e^{AT}-I)Bu[k]
$$

as an exact solution for this problem.
Then, it says that applying the approximation $ e^{AT} = (e^{-AT})^{-1} \approx (I-AT)^{-1} $ , this solution becomes identical to the one derived with backward Euler method.

However, this approximation leads to a different result with the approximation
$
x[k+1] \approx x[k] + T(Ax[k+1] + Bu[k+1])
$ . The first one, Wikipedia version, leads

$$
x[k+1] = A_dx[k] + B_du[k]
$$

but the latter (which I believe is correct)

$$
x[k+1] = A_dx[k] + B_du[k+1]
$$

for $ A_d = (I-AT)^{-1} $ and $ B_d = (I-AT)^{-1}BT $.

What am I missing in the first approximation?

Comment: I think I'll agree with you. What is stated in wikipedia is not totally correct, in the sense that from the closed form expresion of $x[k+1]$ they obtain, they approximated the convolution integral using $u[k]$, so you can never obtain the backward euler approximation with a $u[k+1]$ term. However, you can repeat the whole procedure and approximate the convolution integral with a $u[k+1]$ term too: approximating an integral using the endpoint on the left or on the right is basically the same in the limit. In this way you could obtain the approximation you wanted. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. So, I concluded, "an exact solution" is implicitly assuming that u is u(kT) for the term "We also assume that u is constant during the integral." And this is not valid for the backward version (u must be u((k+1)T)).